# paper-radio-group takes selection on second click only

Tags: javascript, polymer

This is probably something very simple but I cannot figure it out right now. I have a polymer paper-radio-group with various buttons, but the selection is not taken until the second click.

```
<paper-radio-group selected="{{radioSelected}}" on-change="viewChanger">
    <paper-radio-button name="none">None</paper-radio-button>
    <paper-radio-button name="sidebyside">Side by side</paper-radio-button>
    <paper-radio-button name="popup">Pop-up</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
```

And the JS:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'x-menu',
  properties: {
      radioSelected: {
         type: String,
         value: "none"
      }
  },
  viewChanger: function() {
    console.log(this.radioSelected);
  }
});
```

Thanks for your help. I'm new to Polymer.

Comment: Can you put the issue here? https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-radio-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this better:

```
<paper-radio-group selected="{{radioSelected}}">
  <paper-radio-button name="none">None</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="sidebyside">Side by side</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="popup">Pop-up</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
```

And your JS:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'x-menu',
  properties: {

    radioSelected: {
      type: String,
      value: "none",
      observer: '_radioGroupChanged'
    }
  },

  _radioGroupChanged: function(radioSelected) {
    console.log(radioSelected);
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!